# Trouble handling simultaneous PhD application in two different teams of the same institute

Tags: phd, etiquette, application

So, there are team A and team B of the same institute and I have been interested in both since I started looking for a PhD, especially in team B.

I have been writing an application for team B but had trouble finishing it because they asked for so many thinks it was discouraging (like I had a hard time writing a two pages research statement because I did not really get what they were expecting from me in this letter).

In the meantime, I met a professor from team A that talked me about a PhD subject A. I had a good feeling so I applied and I got invited to the institute for interviews with the team A. At this point I have thought it would be weird to apply to team B too.

It went well and after this visit, I thought team A and the institute were amazing, however, talking all day long with researcher about what I wanted to do, I realized that 50% of the subject A is not really aligned with what I want to do, while team B researches really fit more what I want to work on. So I really regretted I did not apply to them. I mentioned to Supervisor A that I was also considering applying to team B.

So the following day, thinking I would regret it too much if I did not try, I finalized my application for team B, which was then far easier to do since thanks to the interviews, I finally knew what they wanted to know from me in the research statement. Since the leader of team B was also one of my interviewers, I also wrote him a short mail to let him know that I applied to his team as well.

The thing is, he answered me that "he would not interfere with my application in team A.." 
I guess he can't "steal me" while I am in an application process with team A, I did not see it that way when applying...

So now I am concerned about 3 things:

- Did I made a faux pas by sending this mail?
- It seems that my only chance for my application to be considered by team B would be to refuse team A proposal and I don't want to find myself without any option since my other applications did not succeed.
- Moreover, I am not even sure Team B would have any vacancies for a PhD

Comment: Did you get an offer from Team A already?

Comment: @silvado No yet, they will get back to me in the following days.

Comment: So now I did get an offer from Team A.